# How do file systems track free space

Tags: filesystems

I'm writing a program that needs to read and write lots of data in random order, and since I don't want to use hundreds of small files, I'm trying to develop a sort of virtual file system that writes to one large file that keeps track of where the "files" are in the "disk" file.

Thus, I've been trying to find detailed information about file system implementations, but theres one thing that never seems to be explained in a way I can understand: How does the file system track free/deleted sectors for new file creation? FAT, for example, has an index of all sectors at the beginning that seems to be the only place that holds this information, but searching the index for a new area of free space in a linear, O(n) fashion seems like it would be rather inefficient, especially if there are no deleted sectors and you have to insert something at the end of the list. Am I missing something, or is this is how file systems really detect unused sectors for writing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a helpful PDF explaining how free space is mapped in linux file systems. This is more along the lines of what I was looking for.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2010/ols2010-pages-121-132.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the overall file system architecture. It can be a linear list of free pages, or the free space can be counted in the same way as other files (eg. linked lists).

Practically developing an efficient file system is quite serious task for a side task that you have. So it makes sense to use some already created virtual file system, such as the one CodeBase offers or our [Solid File System](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/).

Answer (score -2):

it's just like a link list: each file may be seperated into many partitions and at the end of the partition each partition it's refering to begining of the next the same goes for the free speaces. think of free space as one large file that contains every byte which is not inside another file!

Comment: may i ask why a downvote? [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) is my resource for this answer.

Comment: It is one valid for specific for one, highly deprecated filesystem: FAT